# else statement not triggering else

Tags: php, mysql, date, if-statement

I am trying to create a script where if the date is later than today then it will display an item from the table in MySQL.

```
$query = $dbc->query("SELECT event_id, name, location, image, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS Date, Date as FormatDate
                    FROM events
                    ORDER BY FormatDate ASC
            ");
            $results = $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                while($row = $query->fetch()){
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $image = $row['image'];
                    $location = $row['location'];
                    $Date = $row['Date'];
                    $Date = strtotime($Date);
                    $Date = date('d-M-Y', $Date);
                    $Data = explode("-", $Date);

                        if (strtotime($Date) >= time()){
                        $page->body("
                            <div class=\"event\">test
                                    <img src=\"$image\" alt=\"$name\" class=\"event_image\"/> 
                                    <p class=\"event_title\">$name</p>
                                    <p class=\"event_location\">$location</p>
                                    <p class=\"event_time\">$Data[0] $Data[1] $Data[2]</p>
                            </div>
                            ");
                    }else{

                $page->body ("
                        <!-- alrge grey text 100% span -->
                            <div class=\"event\">
                                <p>There are currently no events happening.</p>
                            </div>

                            ");     
            }

                }

        }
```

When I add an event to the table with a later date than today it adds successfully and the script runs and I can see the event printed out on the page because the date if greater than time().

But if I clear the MySql table of all events then it doesn't bring back the else statement "There are currently no events happening".

I am stumped as to why the else statement doesn't bring back the failed notification if there is nothing in the table that is later than today.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your code only says *for every row found, if this row is today or later ... else output "no events happening".* The `else` only pertains to every row. If no row is found, it doesn't even go into the loop. Fix your logic.

Answer (score 2):

> But if I clear the MySql table of all events then it doesn't bring back the else statement "There are currently no events happening".

The `while` statement will only execute if there are rows to process. Since you've cleared the table, it will never enter the `while` loop, and the `else` branch will never be encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are no rows to fetch and your code is not going inside while loop when your table is empty.

HTH!